# Custom C# Installer using MEF

Tags: c#, .net, installation, uninstallation, rollback

My company is currently building a custom installer the approach we are using is a main exe that loads custom built dlls using mef then calls each dll to do there specific job unpack files create registry entries install windows service etc.

Each dll does its own isolated install job.

We also want to handle uninstall and rollback, and we do not want to use msi or wix or any other install interface just solely c#.

Is this a good approach to building a custom installer? Any ideas on how to handle the rollback and uninstall will we run into problems using this approach?

Comment: "we do not want to use msi or wix or any other install interface"

Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Do you have some specific requirement that those tools do not meet?

Comment: Just the learning curve involved in using those tools, plus we want total control over our product and not need have to worry about licence issues and third party software.